# How to make component-based single page web application?

Tags: javascript, web, client-side

This is probably a very vague question.

Suppose I have a single-page web application, which uses `AJAX` to communicate with REST services in the server. It consists of one monolithic `HTML` and one monolithic `CSS` file, which include all forms, dialogs and other GUI elements the application should display on the screen.

Now I would like to break it down into components (e.g. *login form*, *sign-up form*, *error dialog*, etc.). I guess each component should contain its own `HTML`, `CSS`, and `JavaScript` files. Besides there should be some mechanism to load all these components and put them together to display in the page.

What are the recommended approaches/patterns to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest starting your research on building single page js apps by looking at the Todo MVC projects.

https://github.com/addyosmani/todomvc

From the URL above

> To help solve this problem, we created TodoMVC - a project which
>   offers the same Todo application implemented using MV* concepts in
>   most of the popular JavaScript MV* frameworks of today.

So, this will show how the same project's built with different libs and you can try one or more out and see what best works for you.